# Session Data with Durandal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, durandal

I am just getting started with Durandal.js so excuse me for the silly quesstion...

When a user makes it's first request to the app it is asked to choose a 'profile kind', and I need it to be accessible to every other view model in the web site, I first though of creating this property in the shell viewmodel, but don't how to do it.

How is the best way to store data in a Session like mode in a Durandal SPA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an amd module for what data you need to store.

Then just require that module as a dependency for whatever other modules that need it.

Sort of like this:

### session module

```
define(function () {
    return {
        someVariable: 'value1',
        someVariable2: 'value2'
    }
})
```

### some other module

```
define(['session'], function(session) {
    return {
        getValue1: function () {
            return session.someVariable;
        },
        obs1: ko.observable(session.someVariable2)
    }
})
```

EDIT**
AMD modules are there to not pollute the global namespace of the window object.  But if you would rather not require your session as a dependency and just access it through a global variable then that is perfectly fine.

you can declare it in your `shell.js` if you would like and do something like:

```
define(function () {
    window.session = { someVariable: 'value1', someVariable2: 'value2' };
})
```

then inside some other module you can access the session object like so:

```
define(function() {
    return {
        getValue1: function () {
            return session.someVariable;
        },
        obs1: ko.observable(session.someVariable2)
    }
})
```

This information will not be persisted between page refreshes.. its only in-memory.
If your looking to persist the session data I would not look into persisting any information on the client unless you planned on making your app an off-line application.
An offline application is an app that works even w/out internet access.  But if your app requires that the user is always connected to the internet then I would just store the session data on the server.  So, just use web services to persist the session data and retrieve it.

You can tie the session on the server to the client by using a cookie.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this method is that the session data is not persisted in case a user hits the refresh button on the page, as it would be with session data.  I use this same method in my Durandal app's and it can be a bit of a problem if you are relying on some data in the session module.

Comment: Thansk, The first thing I done was just that, but besides the data not beeing persisted one other thing that concerns me is the need of requiring it on every View Model, is there a way to globally require it on shell.js or something like that?

Comment: Would there be any downsides of using localeStorage to keep data for later (other viewmodels)?

Comment: if you want your app to work offline then localestorage is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Evan's answer, which is definitively the correct AMD approach... have you considered using a global object for that purpose?

in main.js

```
window.myApp = {
    prop1: 'value',
    subOne: {
         prop1: 'value'
    } 
   ... 
}
```

That will allow you to access the global `myApp` object everywhere. I know that some people will consider that as global namespace pollution and in general a bad practice, but in a SPA project (where you control `window`) I'd consider this still a viable approach.