# DurandalJS: Access data from another view model

Tags: javascript, durandal

Here's my setup:

```
• shell
  - sidebar (composition)
  - page 1 (tab 1)
  - page 2 (tab 2)
```

Each of these has its own view model which are returned as constructor functions. I have a big chunk of data coming in from the server. Part of it goes to the sidebar, while the rest goes inside the two pages. I could `GET` the data from the shell and use an `app.trigger` that would load the data inside the sidebar and page 1, but how could I then access the data from page 2 after I switch tabs if the trigger was already fired?

Is there a way to store this data somewhere and pick them up after I finish loading a certain view model?

Comment: Why can't page 2 listen for the event and hold the reference until it needs it?

Comment: Consider using a shared AMD module as discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490401/session-data-with-durandal/17493875#17493875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write AMD module responsible for loading data and persisting them on client side. But if you share data between viewmodels I would advise you to use breeze.js - special JavaScript library which provides ways to handle rich data in web applications.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. A lot to digest. I understand that these are client side features, but are there any other disadvantages of not using server-side breeze except not being able to use the EntityQuery methods?

Comment: @Norbert, As far I know You are able to use EntityQuery in only-client-side Breeze. Only disadvantage is duplicating Your model on client side. Feel free to check NoDB, ESPN or Edmunds Samples from Breeze.js website - they show a way to use Breeze.js without using server-side Breeze controller and metadata