# Can't require('durandal/app') in shell.js

Tags: durandal

This is my `shell.html` defining a navbar, pretty much lifted straight from the tute.

```
<div>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
        <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">

          <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }"><span><i data-bind="attr: { class: glyph }"></i> <span data-bind="text: title"></span></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <span class="nav">
        Welcome <span data-bind="text: app.user.name()"></span>
      </span>
      <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid page-host" data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance' }"></div>
</div>
```

This is the problem part:

```
<span data-bind="text: app.user.name()"></span>
```

`user` is a property I add to `app` right after it's created. It is updated by the view models for log in and log out.

To get that binding to work I need to bring the object into scope in the view model. Normally I would do that like this: `var app = require('durandal/app');`. In most view models this is no problem. But view management gets seriously messed up when I do it in shell.js.

All I'm trying to do is fish out some app state to indicate whether the user is currently logged in.

There are two possible solutions

- Get app into scope somehow
- Manage application state in some other way that is in scope in shell.js

I'm sure this is trivial to old hands; I await your wisdom. Searching google didn't work well because "app" is way too broad a search term.

---

I dodged the problem by tacking user onto document instead of app, but that's hideous. I'm all ears for the right way to do this.

Interestingly, HTML5 browsers define `sessionStorage` for exactly the purpose to which I polluted `document`. If you do this in your boot code

```
if (typeof(document.sessionStorage) == undefined) document.sessionStorage = {};
```

then you can assume it exists in the rest of your app.
We can't *count* on browser support, but it's not hard to check and if necessary create it. If you look up sessionStorage you'll see a warning that the contents will be lost at the next page load, but in a SPA that matters not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did in our Durandal app is create a separate static module called `config`, which contains, among other properties, an observable property called `userName`.

At the top of your module (the shell.js file, in this case), put the following:

```
define([
        'durandal/system',
        'durandal/activator',
        'plugins/router',
        'durandal/app',
        ...
        'config'
    ],
    function(system, activator, router, app,..., config) {
    }
);
```

The `config` module should be static, which means that it should return an object literal, not a constructor function.

Your `config` module might look something like this (bare bones):

```
define('config', ['knockout'],
    function(ko) {
        var userName = ko.observable('');

        return {
            userName: userName
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this (most probably the right one), would be using a shared AMD module as discussed in [Session Data with Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490401/session-data-with-durandal/17493875#17493875).

Comment: +1 for handing me the right nomenclature. Much easier to research now.